# A question on cross-reference

Tags: cross-referencing

Suppose I have several sections in my document. How may I cross-reference to a section so that it is updated if I make more sections?

Comment: See section 2.8 of [lshort](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) for the basics; please make your question more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a label for the referenced section(s), and then refer to it (them) from anywhere else. `LaTeX` will automatically change the references if new sections are added. E.g.,

```
\section{The Referred Section}
\label{sec:mysectionlabel} % or whatever unique label you wish to use

% ... 

\section{Another Section}
\label{sec:anotherseclabel}  % only if you need to refer to this one also

As we mentioned in \S \ref{sec:mysectionlabel} above, ...
```